# Executing an R file in one container while mounting a volume containing packages

Tags: r, docker

I am using WSL2 with Ubuntu on Windows 11. I have the following folder setup:

```
Code
|--- Dockerfile
|--- iris.R
R
|--- Dockerfile
|--- packages.R
|--- packages.txt
Results (an empty folder)
```

My goals are the following:

1. Create a container based on the R folder, resulting in a volume.
2. Mount the volume onto this second container.
3. Have it detect that the packages were already installed from the volume.
4. Execute iris.R.
5. Have it save its output to the Results folder, mounted onto my local Results folder (I am not worried about this step for the time being, but if you feel like telling me how to do this step, by all means).

I understand that the eventual goal should be to get these into a docker-compose file, but I'd like to get these working directly in the CLI before I go there.

### Step 1

R/Dockerfile:

```
#### INITIAL SETUP
FROM r-base:4.2.2

# Define the date (YYYY-MM-DD) at build time
ARG WHEN
ENV WHEN = $WHEN

# Copy packages.txt
COPY . /home/

# Define the working directory
WORKDIR /home/

# Execute R from the terminal
CMD ["Rscript", "packages.R"]
```

R/packages.R:

```r
when <- gsub("= ", "", Sys.getenv("WHEN"))

options(repos = list(CRAN = paste0('http:/mran.revolutionanalytics.com/snapshot/', when)))

install.packages(readLines('packages.txt'))
```

R/packages.txt:

```
ggplot2
```

Here are the commands I've executed in the R folder:

```
docker build --network=plot-network:first --build-arg WHEN=2022-12-29 -t package:first .
docker volume create packages
docker run -d --network=plot-network:first -v packages:/home --rm package:first
```

I understand that this creates a `packages` volume, which is necessary since once the container is done, the data (i.e., the packages that were installed) are not retained.

### Steps 2-3

Here's where I'm stuck. Now we go to the Code folder:

Code/Dockerfile:

```
#### INITIAL SETUP
FROM r-base:4.2.2

# Set an environment variable at runtime for the separate directory
ENV MAINDIR /home/

# Copy the file to a path in the container
COPY . ${MAINDIR}

# Set working directory
WORKDIR $MAINDIR

# Append Rscript to code
ENTRYPOINT ["Rscript"]
```

Code/iris.R:

```
library(ggplot2)
args <- commandArgs(trailingOnly = TRUE)

p <- ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width,
                 color = Species)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.grid = element_blank()) +
  xlab("Sepal Length") +
  ylab("Sepal Width") +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(4, 8), breaks = seq(4, 8, 0.5)) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(2, 5), breaks = 2:5)

ggsave(filename = args[1])
```

The obvious first command to execute is

```
docker build -t plot:first .
```

The second command isn't quite as obvious. `Rscript iris.R` should execute `iris.R`, but I have not figured out how to mount the volume properly so that `iris.R` is detected.

```
docker run --network=plot-network:first -v packages:/home/ plot:first iris.R
Fatal error: cannot open file 'iris.R': No such file or directory
```

I commented out the `ENTRYPOINT ["Rscript"]` above and was trying to figure out why `iris.R` was not showing up as `Rscript iris.R` was telling me it was not in the directory, and executed the following:

```
docker run --network=plot-network:first -v packages:/home/ plot:first R -e "list.files()"
```

This lists the files in the directory and gave me the following:

```r
list.files()
[1] "docker"       "Dockerfile"   "packages.R"   "packages.txt"
```

It does not detect iris.R in here.

It seems to detect the files originally in the R folder. But concerningly, it does *not* detect the installed packages that I thought I threw into the `packages` volume.

When the `docker run` command in **Step 1** was executed, as the packages were being installed, R told me:

```
Installing package into ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
```

and clearly this `/usr/` directory was not brought into the volume (as evidenced by `list.files()` above).

What am I doing wrong here?

### Why do this?

I've been asked this question by others who have provided me some assistance: the reason for this is because package installation is time-consuming, and it would be ideal to just reference one container which has packages installed so that I don't have to re-install the packages every time I build a new container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the "Why do this" I understand that you are looking to skip installing packages when building new containers.

Therefore, I would suggest skipping the volumes part all together, and just using the first container as a source for the second container.

The Code/Dockerfile first line would be:

```
From package:first
```

The volume is used to share data between multiple containers at the same time, so unless that's what you want, I wouldn't recommend using it for such scenario.

> It seems to detect the files originally in the R folder. But concerningly, it does not detect the installed packages that I thought I threw into the packages volume.

This is because the volume is mounting the /home dir, where the packages are being downloaded and installed in different directories. From the log of the packages container:

> installing to
> /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/00LOCK-tibble/00new/tibble/libs

and

> The downloaded source packages are in
> ‘/tmp/Rtmp7ow0xd/downloaded_packages’

Using the volumes will add more complexity that is not needed, since the packages installed would be split into multiple folders.

Finally, the iris.R file is not being found since the volume mount is overriding it with the files of the packages container.

I suggest the below:

1. Keep R/Dockerfile as is.
2. Build the packages container.
3. Use the packages container as the source for the plot container
4. Build the plot container
5. Run the plot container without volumes (the /home dir
   would still have the files of the packages container, you can add a
   line to clean the dir up before copying the iris.R file to it).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you elaborate on the execution of step 5? It appears that R is not detecting the ggplot2 package even after the packages container is the new source for the Dockerfile.

Comment: To be clear, this is what I did: `docker run --network=plot-network:first plot:first ./iris.R ./Results/` to which I received the response `Error in library(ggplot2) : there is no package called ‘ggplot2’
Execution halted`.

Comment: I have asked a follow-up question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74999689/docker-question-on-running-commands-in-a-child-image-after-commands-in-a-parent.

Comment: After some modifications after reading your answer, I got this to work. Thank you. The main thing that needs to happen is that the package installation needs to be under `RUN` as opposed to `CMD`.