# Docker question on running commands in a child image after commands in a parent image

Tags: r, docker, dockerfile

This is based on the answer I was given at [Executing an R file in one container while mounting a volume containing packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74957940/executing-an-r-file-in-one-container-while-mounting-a-volume-containing-packages). Please note that I am *not* using docker-compose, but I intend on moving to that once I get this working via the CLI.

### Files and Folders

I have the following folder setup:

```
Code
|--- Dockerfile
|--- iris.R
R
|--- Dockerfile
|--- packages.R
|--- packages.txt
Results (an empty folder)
```

R/Dockerfile:

```
#### INITIAL SETUP
FROM r-base:4.2.2

# Copy packages.txt
COPY . /home/

# Define the working directory
WORKDIR /home/

# Execute R from the terminal
CMD ["Rscript", "./packages.R"]
```

R/packages.R:

```r
install.packages(readLines('packages.txt'))
```

R/packages.txt:

```
ggplot2
```

Code/iris.R:

```
library(ggplot2)
args <- commandArgs(trailingOnly = TRUE)

p <- ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width,
                 color = Species)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.grid = element_blank()) +
  xlab("Sepal Length") +
  ylab("Sepal Width") +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(4, 8), breaks = seq(4, 8, 0.5)) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(2, 5), breaks = 2:5)
```

Code/Dockerfile:

```
#### INITIAL SETUP
FROM package:first

# Set an environment variable at runtime for the separate directory
ENV MAINDIR /home/

# Copy the file to a path in the container
COPY . ${MAINDIR}

# Set working directory
WORKDIR $MAINDIR
```

### CLI Commands

#### In the R folder:

```
docker build -t package:first .
docker run -t package:first
```

#### In the Code folder:

```
docker build -t test . 
docker run -t test
```

### What I'm trying to do

The code runs above as expected, without issues. However, what I want to happen is for `Rscript iris.R` to be executed in the CLI after running the Docker folder.

### Things I have tried

1. Adding the following line to Code/Dockerfile:

```
CMD ["Rscript", "iris.R"]
```

When I execute the following in the Code folder, the `CMD ["Rscript", "./packages.R"]` from Code/Dockerfile clearly gets ignored, because `ggplot2` is not installed.

```
docker build -t test . 
docker run -t test
Sending build context to Docker daemon  3.072kB
Step 1/5 : FROM package:first
 ---> 570ce8dfefc7
Step 2/5 : ENV MAINDIR /home/
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 204f133ca09b
Step 3/5 : COPY . ${MAINDIR}
 ---> 99e453b90204
Step 4/5 : WORKDIR $MAINDIR
 ---> Running in 1a6be0dfb5bb
Removing intermediate container 1a6be0dfb5bb
 ---> 1582e287cdcd
Step 5/5 : CMD ["Rscript", "iris.R"]
 ---> Running in e6a843cf9a2e
Removing intermediate container e6a843cf9a2e
 ---> b57708b42a89
Successfully built b57708b42a89
Successfully tagged test:latest
Error in library(ggplot2) : there is no package called ‘ggplot2’
Execution halted
```

2. Adding the following line to Code/Dockerfile:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["Rscript"]
```

I think I can guess why this doesn't work, as I think it would just ignore `CMD ["Rscript", "./packages.R"]` and then append itself to whatever is in `docker run`:

```
docker run -t test ./iris.R
Error in library(ggplot2) : there is no package called ‘ggplot2’
Execution halted
```

3. Keeping Code/Dockerfile as above and then running

```
docker run -t test Rscript ./iris.R
```

Unsurprisingly, this gives the same outcome as my second attempt.

How do I go about approaching this?

Comment: In the base Dockerfile, do you want to `RUN Rscript ./packages.R`, building the dependencies into the image, rather than deferring that installation to be the only thing the container does as its `CMD`?

Comment: @DavidMaze I thought I had tried that earlier and it didn't work, but it appears to work now! Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your base image, you set the `CMD` to run the package installation script.  A container only runs one `CMD`, though, so when the derived image declares its own `CMD` it overrides the base image's `CMD`, and the installation script never gets run.

You most likely want the library dependencies to be built into the (base) image, and not reinstalled every time when you run the container.  Changing `CMD` to `RUN` will do this.  (It's legal to keep the JSON-array syntax if it simplifies things, but it's a little less common for `RUN` lines.)

```bash
# base image R/Dockerfile
RUN Rscript ./packages.R   # not CMD
```

This leaves the base image Dockerfile without a `CMD`.  This is fine; it will inherit the `CMD` from *its* base image (here it will just run `R`).  You do usually want a `CMD` in a final image containing the application or script you actually want to run (for example, your `iris.R`).